# Adding Model Attributes to REST/SOAP API in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest, soap, model

I want to build a MVC application that consumes both REST and SOAP references. I can use the added references as the model but I cannot add attributes like I would be able to if I created the class myself. I want the ability to add `[DataType]`, `[Display]`, `[Required]`, etc... to the properties.

Is there a way to make a wrapper around the existing model/class from the API and add my own attributes?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it would be easier if you create your model with those attributes and the try to map what you've received from your services to your model. You can use AutoMapper that will make your life easier too.